# Raw data of logs record in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics

How can I view the raw data of logs record in Azure functions?

I'm familiar with the "Logs" tab below function monitoring, but it requires a specific query and returns formatted information.

Comment: What do you mean with raw logs, it doesn't get much more raw than using direct kusto queries or you need to export the logs to blob storage as json

Comment: Ok great, I didnt know that. Is it possible to view the results of Kusto queries as JSON or should I export the logs to Blob storage?

Comment: You need to export the logs, unfortunately you cannot output kusto results to json.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @peter bons for pointing out in the right direction. You can navigate to logs directly from your function app left pane and query for traces which gives you detailed logs. You can apply filters too based on your requirement.

[image]

while if you are trying to export the logs you can use export to csv as shown below.

[image]